# android + google API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, error-handling

i am creating a application with using the google map v2  on a real device but i get a problem and the application force close how to fix this after i read many and many solutions none of them worked with me 
it is something about the **fragment**

## manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission 

        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


     <uses-feature 
         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
         android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC6Sh22y4wF_tKlrE2MljwZ7Cd9-8V-Nks"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## java file

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## log cat file

```
04-08 02:29:33.500: D/dalvikvm(25400): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-08 02:29:33.535: D/dalvikvm(25400): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-08 02:29:33.730: D/AndroidRuntime(25400): Shutting down VM
04-08 02:29:33.730: W/dalvikvm(25400): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d4b2a0)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    ... 11 more
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4849)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    ... 21 more
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
04-08 02:29:33.750: E/AndroidRuntime(25400):    ... 24 more
```

Comment: if u want step by step procedure then i can post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error here is:

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

which means that basically `MapFragment` class could not be found. `MapFragment` is part of the `google-play-services` library. To use it you need to import the `google-play-services` into your `workspace` and then reference it from your project, you can reed how it's done in the `first 3 steps` of this blog post I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: sorry i did not take a look