# Android and Google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, error-handling

I have tried every example I saw on the internet about the Google Map and android but all of them did not work.

I tried on the emulator and on a real device but all give me an error about the fragment  and class not found.

I did import the Google Play Service add to the project, put the Google API key but still not work.

This is the last example I used:

## googlemapv2.java

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

## manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission 

        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


     <uses-feature 
         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
         android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API key"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receiving the `fragment/class not found error` then you problem is probably for lacking a good reference of the `google-play-services` library as `MapFragment` is part of this library:

Check that yours `Android Dependencies` folder `(blue)` hold the `google-play-services` `(orange)` inside you will find the `com.google.android.gms.maps` package `(green)` that has the `MapFragment` class `(red)`:

[image]

If this is not the case you can check the first 3 steps of this blog post I wrote to get and idea on how to reference this package correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: you mean the google play package is corrupted ??? but it has the latest update  ... so how to fix this problem ??

Comment: this is strange i do not have the google_play .jar in the android dependecies  but i did import it to the project

Comment: then you did it incorrectly check my blog post for the needed steps.

Comment: sir i checked the properties of the project in the section where the external libraries are added  it show a red  x    beside the google play services library

Comment: have you took a look at my blog post?

Comment: Try to download another sdk (newer), and to place the google-play-services project in a place where it's path will be shorter.

Comment: ok i will download a new sdk from the official android website hope that will solve the problem  because i need this so badly

Comment: i did download the latest update for the sdk API 17 but without ARM SYSTEM IMAGE

Comment: this was just a pic of the SDK manager, you don't need the ARM SYSTEM IMAGE, you need to download the google play services package.

Comment: i did download yesterday the update of the google play service package

Comment: then try to copy it to another location with a shorter path and reference it again following the first 3 steps of the guide.

Comment: thank you  emil i do not know how to thank youu i was the long path wat cause the problem  but now it work but still not gettig the map view i just display the hello world text with a yellow rectangle  a  +   -  sign  instead of the map

Comment: you welcome @user2254979, why won't you accept then the other question I answer for you already with the same question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869159/android-google-api-v2

Comment: so do you have a solution for the last problem ??

Comment: usually this indicates some kind of key problem, but open a new question with the relevant details and I will try to help you. 2 advices before you do: 1. regenerate you SHA1 key, by deleting the debug.keystore folder and compiling some project in eclipse. 2. make sure you have turned on the right API in the console, that you are using the Google Maps API V2 for ANDROID and not the regular one.

Comment: actually  i am using the real device so the problem that in the log cat it will not display the errors because as a read before that the google play  it is not supported within the emulators

Comment: you can see the logcat of you device as well if it's connected to your pc, and about the google maps in emulator, read this: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

Comment: i do not have intel processor i have AMD but this is a fantastic document

Comment: I talked about the second part on how to run google maps in the emulator

Comment: i do not have a cpu  as the last required field in the document is this a big deal ??

Comment: sir i tried to use the adb to install the 2 packages but i get this error message on the cmd **the system cannot find  message text  for mssage number 0x2331 in the message file  for Application**

Comment: sorry, never seen this error before. maybe this is not working on AMD proccesors. never tried it.